# What is the rationale behind using non-numeric package component for the version?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, version

In ubuntu (and not only in ubuntu) default repository you could see a package version like `2.2.14-5ubuntu8.12`.

Why do the maintainers give such a weird version in the *central package repository*?

What tasks the `2.2.14-42` version wouldn't solve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Namespace:

- `2.2.14` is the version number from the upstream package (from apache.org)
- `-5` is the debian package version
- on top of which Ubuntu does some modification, each iteration increasing the version number. `ubuntu8.12`

Had Debian made a `-6` and Ubuntu chosen to take it, you'd have had a `2.2.14-6` in Ubuntu and probably a `2.2.14-6ubuntu1` and so on, and the number would have been bigger which is important if you want it to be considered an upgrade by `apt`.

If you want to do modifications yourself, you'll probably want to add your own namespace: 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.12zerkms1

Once Ubuntu releases a 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.13 or 2.2.14-5ubuntu9 or 2.2.14-6, that will be an upgrade.

Answer (score 8):

Part of the version string is the "upstream" version.  *Upstream* means towards the original source, and *downstream* means toward the distro package.  I think generally there isn't really anything in between this, so there are basically two stages (the original source, and the compiled distro package).

For example, bash-4.2.39 is just that.  The original source for bash-4.2.39 is exactly the same, and from the same place, regardless of whether you are using fedora, ubuntu, arch, or anything else.  There is only one source for bash-4.2.39. "4.2.39" would be what I referred to as the upstream version number.

That one source, however, might be compilable a number of different ways (apart from the system architecture); certainly this is the case for bash.  That's a decision made by the downstream packagers, who may also include things (such as a configuration) not in the original source.  At this point, there may be clear differences between the bash 4.2.39 packaged for ubuntu and the bash 4.2.39 for fedora (and differences between versions of the same distro).  That's mostly indicated by the final part of the version string -- "ubuntu8.12" or whatever.  Further, exactly which distro and distro version the package was compiled for is important because it matches other packages (shared libraries) that this one requires; even if there is a bash 4.2.39 available for ubuntu 10 and 12, they may not be interchangeable.

Stuff like '-42' is indicative of some additional versioning downstream, by the distro.  This may be something to do with configuration differences, distro patching, etc, in which case the same '-42' version may be used in multiple repositories for multiple versions of the distro (and their derivations).

This adds up to a unique version string indicating the *original source version*, the *package version*, and the *specific distro + distro version*.